# no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches argument list

Tags: c++, getline, istream

the fstream and string inlcusions are in the .h file. I've read multiple people's problems but can't seem to apply it to my own. I've tried putting in infile.getfile(dataFile, line)) to no avail. The dataFile is just a list of employees. I still keep getting the same no instance of overloaded function with getfile(dataFile, line)

```
{

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(dataFile);
    if(!infile.good())
    {
        cout << "File is not open";
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(!infile.good())
        {
            string line;
            while (getline(dataFile, line))
            {
                if (line[0] == 'h' ) 
                {
                    HospitalEmployee newEmp;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while (getline(dataFile, line))
```

The first argument is the stream, and the second argument is the string where the line will be assigned. You got the second argument right, but the first argument is a `string` object, not the file stream from which the line will be extracted. You're supposed to pass the stream, `inFile`:

```
while (getline(inFile, line))
//             ^^^^^^
```

Comment: `inFile` is not a file. It is an input file stream.

Comment: No problem at all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `infile.open(dataFile)` suggests that `dataFile` is the string filename and `infile` is the stream.

So, instead of `getline(dataFile, line)`, you mean `getline(infile, line)`.

Typo, I'm sure.